# How is OpenGL and DirectX performance in VMWare Fusion 3?

Tags: vmware-fusion, directx, user-experience

I'm already a VMWare Fusion 2 user and Fusion 3 (just released [here](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/features.html)) has numerous features in conjunction with Snow Leopard.

I'm curious to know if anyone in particular has tried it out and specifically tried out OpenGL 2.1/DirectX 9.0c compatibility. I'll probably buy it anyway but I wanted to hear anyone's experience with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

been running VMWare Fusion 3 for about 2 days now - was really looking forward to it just for the 64-bit OS X kernel support.

Anyway, good news is Fusion 3 is slightly faster, and I'm loving the new Application Start button located in Apple's menu bar.

Bad news - OpenGL 2.1/DirectX 9.0c compatibility still sucks. More games run now - but they still run like molasses on my MBP, and often with graphical glitches. wasn't expecting much though.

Personally, I'd recommend shelling USD$40 for the update, just for the speed increase and better integration alone. However, do it after the serial number debacle is over and VMWare gets it right.

Also - make a backup of your VMs, and give Fusion 3 trial a whirl - decide if it's worth the $40.

Comment: It's safe to say that if you want native gaming performance/capability, BootCamp is your best option.  For running non-graphics intensive apps, Fusion 3 is top notch!  (I was a Beta tester)

Comment: +1 Caliban for the info. I know never to expect hard-core graphical games to perform similar to the non-virtualized solutions, but I was hoping this was a substantial/noticeable increase. But if Fusion3 overall is faster and the other non-gaming features are just as good, I may as well just bite and get the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, EmmEff. I use Fusion largely for .NET development but I miss some of my games and I want to use my MBP exclusively for gaming as well.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at SizeUp, it’s very useful for moving windows between screens and spaces with the keyboard: http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/

Answer (score 1):

I'm using it since it was released (yesterday morning). I love it! Aero support, the start menu, significantly better performance in Windows 7 VMs and a slightly nicer interface make it totally worth it for me.

Comment: + 1 for the info Paperflyer. Thanks for mentioning Windows 7. I've been using the beta but haven't bought it just yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have a mixed set of results. I brought the upgrade and used it since the day it was released. I use Vista 32 and XP for VS2008 (vista) + SQL2008 (on XP) .NET C# Winforms development.

I was happy (despite the awful bug with Exposé + Unity where VMware won’t correctly show the content of Windows windows (lol) when in Exposé), and I think is an improvement over VMware 2.06. It’s faster and has a few more options (The menu is nice as already mentioned).

**However** after following Parallels on twitter and the mixed results, I decided to give Parallels 5 a try. I had a Parallels 1, 2 an 3 license, skipped 4 in favor of VMware.

Parallels 5 compiles and works *noticeably* faster within VS2008. The compilation *clearly* takes less time (didn’t benchmark but after almost two weeks working with a product, I instantly saw the speed increase). My application uses a lot of GDI+ code. I was shocked to see that it was that fast (I was always complaining about slowness in GDI+!). Parallels runs circles around VMware in that aspect.

I have a powerful box (Mac Pro 8 cores 10Gb RAM) but I had that before, so no change between both products. I have them both and I occasionally switch between them (svn update and good to go). The VMs have been *converted* from VMware to Parallels, so I assume that any reinstall will be even better for Parallels (waiting on Win 7 to try both on a fresh install).

Despite all this, Parallels 5 has bugs too. Some details. I’d say you give it a try. Some people think that CPU usage is all that matters, but I don’t agree. VM responsiveness and day-to-day work is what matters. So far, I prefer Parallels. Stil 13 trial days :)